# How/Where do I place my System Message in my Rule so it only appears when needed

Tags: commerce, rules

I have created a RULE, after add product to cart, check the quantity of the items in the cart, if you run into the same item that has a quantity of 1, do not add the new item to the cart.

This seems to be working, but now,  no matter what, it always displays the message "duplicate item has been removed."

So if I add 5 unique items to the cart, they are all placed in the cart, but the duplicate message appears.

When I try to add a duplicate item, the item is not placed in the cart and the duplicate message is displayed.

I only want this message to appear when it actually runs into a dup and did not add the item to the cart. I know the issue is that I have the message on "after add item to cart"

Where should I place this message?

Comment: Hi, could you edit the question and include an export of the Rule? Seeing where you've got it now might make it easier to spot where it should be

Comment: Hi Clive - didn't want you to think I ignore you, but I think I kind of have this figure out.  Not the most glamourous rules layout, but it seems to be working.